# Having Issues with Theme Customization in Flowbite-React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, flowbite

I'm following Flowbite-React's theme customization guide [Option 3: Create a reusable component with a custom theme](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/customize/theme#option-3-create-a-reusable-component-with-a-custom-theme) but having troubles getting it to work. Am I missing something? I am using `"flowbite-react": "^0.4.11"`. Here is my code:

```
"use client";

import { Button } from "flowbite-react";

const customTheme = {
    color: {
        primary: "bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600",
    },
};

export default function MyButton({ children, ...props }) {
    return (
        <Button theme={customTheme} {...props}>
            {children}
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Comment: I am running into this same problem. The only thing I have been able to successfully over ride is the root positions. If I find out anything I will try to respond again.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. Option 3 doesn't work, however, [Option 2: Create a custom theme](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/customize/theme#option-2-create-a-custom-theme) does! Here's the code

```
"use client"

import { Flowbite } from 'flowbite-react';

const customTheme = {
  button: {
    color: {
      primary: 'bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600',
    },
  },
};

export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <Flowbite theme={{ theme: customTheme }}>
      <Button color="primary">Click me</Button>
    </Flowbite>
  );
}
```